# Win API linker error undefined reference to WinMain

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

I'm trying to learn how to make win32 programs in C++ using visual studio code on windows 10, compiling with mingw.

I'm specifically trying to follow this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) and copying and pasting that code gave me the same errors as below (fine with `WinMain` and `-mwindows` but not with `wWinMain` and `-mwindows`). Compiling only (`g++ main.cpp -c`) works fine so I think that this is an issue around linking to windows.h.

This is driving me mad as yesterday it was compiling fine with the `wWinMain` code.

When I enter the following code and compile with `g++ main.cpp -mwindows` everything works fine:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
{
    MessageBox (NULL, L"Hello, Windows!", L"Hello", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I enter this code, I get the error `undefined reference to 'WinMain'`:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPWSTR lpCmd, int nShow)
{
    MessageBox (NULL, L"Hello, Windows!", L"Hello", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it working fine with the first but not the second?

Comment: Have you defined _UNICODE for your project?

Comment: I've included #define UNICODE as per the above if that's what you mean?

Comment: No, define both UNICODE and _UNICODE.

Comment: I've added #ifndef, #define _UNICODE, #endif but that's made no difference and I didn't have that yesterday either

Comment: After a bit of digging, adding the `-municode` flag has allowed it to compile, i.e. `g++ main.cpp -municode`

Comment: `wWinMain` is a MS extension (for MSVC) and might not be available with other tool-chains.

Comment: by idea you need set entry point to `wWinMainCRTStartup`.

Comment: @RbMm I tried that and it didn't make any difference

Comment: @askman - i think you not understand me. use something like [`/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-160). but i guess you try replace `wWinMain` to `wWinMainCRTStartup` which of course is wrong. dont know are *g++* have */ENTRY:SYMBOL*  option, but by *-municode* you implicit replace entry from `WinMainCRTStartup` to `wWinMainCRTStartup`

Answer (score 0):

This was simply resolved by adding `-municode` to the command to compile, i.e. `g++ main.cpp -municode`

I believe this is because `wWinMain` uses unicode strings vs. ANSI in `WinMain`.